# Passing components as prop in React and calling them as JSX tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Lets say I have a wrapper component:

```js
// wrapper that renders component passed as a prop
const Component = (childrenComponent) => <div>{childrenComponent}</div>
```

What I'd like to do is to invoke Component within some page, like:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Page = () => {
  const ChildrenComponent = () => <div>Children Component</div>
  return <Component childrenComponent={ChildrenComponent} />
}
```

This will work well. My question is, given that prop names should be lowerCase, how can I change wrapper component code to be able to invoke ChildrenComponent in a JSX way (, instead of inline {childrenComponent}, while satisfying the requirement to name react components in PascalCase:

```js
// this will not work
const Component = (childrenComponent) => <div><childrenComponent /></div>
```

```js
// this will work but the prop name isn't camelCase
const Component = (ChildrenComponent) => <div><ChildrenComponent /></div>
```

Comment: You can simply alias it before rendering by assigning the prop to a new const: `const Component = props.component`. Then render it: `<Component />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup `Component` like this:

```
const Component = props => {
   return (
   <div>{props.children}</div>
   )
}
```

Using `Component`:

```
<Component>
    <ChildrenComponent/>
</Component>
```

More [reading material](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)  from the docs

Comment: Hi @Noam, thanks, this (and Brian's) comment is the correct answer to my question.
I did however encountered an issue. As I'm using TypeScript, I'm getting ```JSX element type 'ChildComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.```
in the line with ```{!!ChildrenComponent && <ChildrenComponent />}```. The typing of Component props is ```{ childrenComponent?: () => React.ReactChild```. When I use ```{ childrenComponent?: () => any``` it works fine but I would like to avoid returning 'any' when I know it's JSX

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cloneElement` as follows:

```js
const Component = (children, ...props) => {
  const clonedChild = cloneElement(children(), props)
  return <>{clonedChild}</>
}
```

You need to wrap the returning result into a fragment.